# Taking a frictionless object to a full stop given initial velocity and stopping distance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, velocity, distance

I am working on a simplistic simulation program where at some times I have to take an object to a full stop, while only knowing it's velocity and the distance in which it has to stop.

Though, I want it to stop exactly on the point.

I am really bad in maths and physics and I cannot seem to wrap my head around this. I have googled and searched over StackOverflow, but I cannot seem to find anything that would provide the solution. Probably my poor math skills just prevent me from deriving from other functions...

Anyhow, I found on the internet [this formula](https://sciencing.com/calculate-tangential-speed-8532530.html):

> Deceleration may also be calculated as change in speed over distance by using the formula final speed squared (${s_f}^2$) minus initial speed squared (${s_i}^2$) divided by twice the distance ($d$): $({s_f}^2 - {s_i}^2) ÷ 2d$ = deceleration.

So, for a distance ($d = 200$), initial speed ${s_i} = 80$ and final speed ${s_f} = 0$, given the formula, the deceleration is $(0^2 - 80^2) ÷ (2*200) = -6400 ÷ 400 = -16$.

Which will stop within the distance, yes, but not exactly on the point, as can be seen here:

```
+-------+--------------+-------------+---------------+--------------------+
| Frame | Distance (m) | Speed (m/s) | Remainder (m) | Target speed (m/s) |
+-------+--------------+-------------+---------------+--------------------+
|     0 |            0 |          80 |           200 |                 64 |
|     1 |           64 |          64 |           136 |                 48 |
|     2 |          112 |          48 |            88 |                 32 |
|     3 |          144 |          32 |            56 |                 16 |
|     4 |          160 |          16 |            40 |                  0 |
+-------+--------------+-------------+---------------+--------------------+
```

As the object decelerates to $0$, it still has $40$ meters left to travel.

What is the correct formula then?

Comment: From your chart I see that when the object is at $160 m$ he still has a $16 \frac{m}{s} $ speed. At frame 5, it should say Distance: 200 and Speed: 0.

Comment: Target Speed is just what will be the speed at the next frame.

Comment: Your problem isn't that the formula is incorrect, but your integrator in the simulation is incorrect causing the deviation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula $$ a = \frac{ v_{\rm final}^2 - v_{\rm initial}^2}{2\,\text{(distance)}} $$

is correct. The problem you have is that for each time step you assumed the speed is constant to calculate the distance traveled.

The correct integrator for each time step $h$ is

```
t_i = t_prev + h
v_i = v_prev + h*accel
x_i = x_prev + h*(v_i+v_prev)/2
```

which uses the trapezoidal rule for integrating speed into distance.

Here are the results

[image: xcel]

and the formulas behind it

[image: xcel2]

Comment: Oh, great - yeah, wasn't aware of that, the correct integration solved everything. Thanks!